# Counter Occurrences of User Specified String in a Text File

Tags: java, string, full-text-search

Count keeps coming up zero. I'm just trying to read the text file and look for the word, and display the count back to the user.

I'm not sure where it's falling apart. The If statement I think, but not sure where the syntax is going wrong. Thanks for any help!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TextSearchFromFile 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{

    boolean run = true;
    int count = 0;


            //greet user
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "Hello, today you will be searching through a text file on the harddrive. \n"
                + "The Text File is a 300 page fantasy manuscript written by: Adam\n"
                + "This exercise was intended to have the user enter the file, but since \n"
                + "you, the user, don't know which file the text to search is that is a \n"
                + "bit difficult.\n\n"
                + "On the next window you will be prompted to enter a string of characters.\n"
                + "Feel free to enter that string and see if it is somewhere in 300 pages\n"
                + "and 102,133 words. Have fun.", 
                "Text Search", 
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    while (run)
    {
        try
        {
                //open the file
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("An Everthrone Tale 1.txt"));

                //prompt user for word
            CharSequence findWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                    "Enter the word to search for:", 
                    "Text Search", 
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            count = 0;


            while (scanner.hasNext())
            {

                if ((scanner.next()).contains(findWord))
                {
                    count++;
                }

            } //end search loop


                //output results to user
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                    "The results of your search are as follows: \n"
                    + "Your String: " + findWord + "\n"
                    + "Was found: " + count + " times.\n"
                    + "Within the file: An Ever Throne Tale 1.txt", 
                    "Text Search",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        } //end try
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                    "Thank you for using the Text Search.", 
                    "Text Search", 
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    } //end run loop
} // end main
} // end class
```

EDIT:
Need help again. The instructor changed the parameters of the project and now I need to find word fragments like "th" or "en" and count those as well.

This I feel is beyond what he has taught and I have no idea how to make that work. I've googled until I can't google anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide a `File` Object to `Scanner` in order to read the file, currently everything is getting searched in a String **"An Everthrone Tale 1.txt"**

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("An Everthrone Tale 1.txt"));
```

And for searching a word, you need to do like this:

```
         while (scanner.hasNext())
         {
             if (findWord.equals(scanner.next()))
             {
                 count++;
             }
        }
```

and if you want to perform **`case-insensitive`** search then use `String#equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `String#equals`

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried that just a few minutes before your post. Still always returns a count value of zero.

Comment: Sanjeev, still no joy. I've tried a couple other ideas, but nothing seems to work. I'm missing something that's probably easy.

Comment: You need to remove else block, use same code i have posted

Comment: The only exception is the nullpointer on cancel because I haven't added the catch for it.

Comment: @Adam Please read my comments and you will get to know the problem

Comment: THAT worked! Thanks much Sanjeev! Crazy, can you explain why that made the difference? I'm still new to coding, I don't understand why that would make the difference.

Comment: because if the first word do not match the find word it will go to else block and close the scanner then breaks. so you will only get `0`

Comment: any chance you could assist me again? I changed the code to reflect a .contains but what he is looking for is word fragments even with spaces in between.

Comment: @Adam Kindly ask a new question